# Bootstrap modal is not working with jQuery 1.8.2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use Bootstrap version 3 on a website where jQuery version 1.8.x is installed. I can't upgrade jQuery because of some other reasons. When I try to use data-model attribute, it says “`emulateTransitionEnd` is not a function.”

Below is my code.

```
 <p class="text-login"><?php echo $this->__('Already registered?') ?> 
   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><?php echo $this->__('LOGIN HERE')?></a>
  </p>
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

Content

</div>
```

When I click on “Login Here”, it does not load the content `<div>` and shows the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 requires jQuery version 1.9 or higher.

You need to either upgrade jQuery or downgrade to Bootstrap 2.

Comment: By downgrading bootstrap `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` are not working and by upgrading jquery many other jquery working functions get stop. anyway, thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to all the version after jquery 1.9 including 1.9 it requires bootstrap version 3 .

So in your case better upgrade your jquery version to 1.9 or higher because ur using bootstarp 3 so i would suggest upgrade jquery